# papyrus sysML profile installation - confguration conflict

Tags: papyrus, sysml

This might be a newbee eclipse/payrus question but I am stuck on trying to configure papyrus (an eclipse UML Model editor) to use sysML profile (https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/papyrus-sysml-16).

The procedure consist in downloading a plugin from the eclipse marketplace. Before doing this I updated my current install which led to the the update of the UML plugin 6.0.0.202111241033.
After that I came to install the sysML plugin but payrus got stuck on a conflict [image]

I browsed the installed plugins but can't uninstall any of the UML plugins.

**QUESTION : How can i get sysML to work with papyrus and resolv that conflicting configuration (using UML AND sysML ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears that using a more [basic version of eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/2021-09/R/eclipse-modeling-2021-09-R-win32-x86_64.zip)  and then installing the papyrus sysML plugin worked. The "standard" papyrus is bundled to create UML model.